# Nifi - activate a flow file after a previous flow file goes through the downstream completely

Tags: apache-nifi

Hello I am trying to make a data flow through Nifi which are listFile -> fetchFile -> data transformation -> putKudu

However, I want to somehow pause the fetchFile processor or hold on to the flowfiles received from the local server until a previous flowfile completely goes through the downstream, after putKudu processor, then release the next flowfile one by one.

I looked at Wait and Notify processors but could not find a way to notify the next flowfilw in the queue to be released.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve what you want by putting all processors after FetchFile in a Process Group with an input port. Connect the FetchFile to the process group. Then you configure the Process Group itself to have a  Flowfile concurrency of 1.

This should cause the input port inside the process group to only accept one file when the prevoious is done.